# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moviepy' although installed

Tags: python, moviepy, modulenotfounderror

When I run:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\PycharmProjects\moviepy_1\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from moviepy.editor import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moviepy'
```

However, when I check pip list in command prompt I can see it's installed (along with everything else it needs, ffmpeg, numpy, etc.)

Why can't my program find the moviepy module? Is it looking in the wrong place? How do I find out where it is looking, how do I tell it to look in the right place?

I am using Windows 10. I am not using a virtual environment. I'm using the PyCharm IDE. Please be explicit with your answer, I have only a basic understanding of Python and programming.

Comment: if you open Python in terminal (type `python`, hit Enter), then say `import moviepy` does it work?

Comment: @ManishDash yes it does. I'm not sure what that means. Does that mean there's something wrong with my IDE?

Comment: maybe your project isn't using the right python interpreter, run python -v both on a terminal and in the IDE and see if the versions match

Comment: @HitLuca running python -v in the terminal says, among other things, "Python 3.10.4" . In PyCharm, under Settings > Project > Python Interpreter, it says "Python 3.10". I assume this means the versions indeed match.

Comment: in Pycharm, at bottom right you should see "Python 3.10" or something similar. Click that and then click interpreter settings. This should open a window and all the packages loaded should be listed. Check if you have the `moviepy` package listed there

Comment: @ManishDash that did it! Thank you! I was able to install moviepy from that menu.

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed in the comments, the issue is that the Python interpreter that being used by your command terminal is different than the one being used by Pycharm IDE. You have `moviepy` installed in the terminal's python env, but not in the Pycharm IDE.

To make sure that the Pycharm IDE's interpreter has the package or install new packages:

- in Pycharm IDE at bottom right look for "Python 3.10" or something similar.
- Click that and then click interpreter settings.
- This should open a window and all the packages loaded should be listed. Here you can add new packages as well